# No puedo mostrar bien un acordeón de bootstrap en el template “lineman-angular-template”

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap

Estoy utilizando el siguiente template con lineman: h ttps://github.com/linemanjs/lineman-angular-template

Quiero montar el acordeon que sale en el siguiente ejemplo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ToGJCbFOEmD46XDHLtt1?p=preview

Y también el acordeón de ejemplo que viene en la pagina de bootstrap.

En todos dos al parecer veo que carga bien las cosas de angular, pero parece que fallara en el estilo. Ya revise pero no veo fallas en los import de los css, las rutas estan bien.

¿De pronto alguien tuvo estos problemas montando elementos de bootstrap?

Pongo pantallazos de como se muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código no lo pude hacer correr bien en este editor, en el enlace corre bien.

example.js

```js
 

var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainController', 
function ($scope) {
$scope.items = [
                    {
                        name: "item1",
                        desc: "Item 1",
                        subitems: [
                            {
                                name: "subitem1",
                                desc: "Sub-Item 1"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "subitem2",
                                desc: "Sub-Item 2"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "subitem2",
                                desc: "Sub-Item 2"
                            }]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "item2",
                        desc: "Item 2",
                        subitems: [
                            {
                                name: "subitem1",
                                desc: "Sub-Item 1"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "subitem2",
                                desc: "Sub-Item 2"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "subitem2",
                                desc: "Sub-Item 2"
                            }]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "item3",
                        desc: "Item 3",
                        subitems: [
                            {
                                name: "subitem1",
                                desc: "Sub-Item 1"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "subitem2",
                                desc: "Sub-Item 2"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "subitem2",
                                desc: "Sub-Item 2"
                            }]
                    }
                ];

$scope.default = $scope.items[2];
});

app.controller('ItemController', ['$scope', function (scope) {

                scope.$parent.isopen = (scope.$parent.default === scope.item);

                scope.$watch('isopen', function (newvalue, oldvalue, scope) {
                    scope.$parent.isopen = newvalue;
                });

            }]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

 <div class="mycontainer" ng-controller="MainController">
        <div class="left-nav">
            <accordion close-others="true" >
                  <accordion-group  is-open="isopen"
                      ng-repeat="item in items" 
                      ng-controller="ItemController">
                      <accordion-heading >
                        {{item.desc}} - {{isopen}}
                          <i class="pull-right glyphicon" 
                                ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isopen}"></i>
                      </accordion-heading>
                  </accordion-group>
              </accordion>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El plunker que pones se ve bien. Cual es el resultado que esperas?

Comment: Hay un botón que dice "Ejecutar" y le doy click, pero me saca errores. Solo es acá...
De todos modos veo que es problema de la instalación de bootstrap en el template, para ningún componente me funciona el estilo.